# Anyway to configure server URL while running a docker image? (instead of hard coding in app)

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, express, ansible

I have an web application that is build using Angular 7 and I need to make an API call to get some data that I display in the App.

The API end point is an express server in node.js and it has some configuration to enable CORS from the web app's URL

I have created separate docker images for the Web App and the Middleware service and I plan to deploy them in the same server (linux machine on a cloud VM with some IP - a.b.c.d)

Since I know the IP of this VM I can hard code the API URL as a.b.c.d/api/foo in the Web App (Angular service) and white list the web app's URL in the middleware as a.b.c.d:3000

But there are situations where the IP address of the VM might change in the future and we also are going to automate the VM creation in the cloud and deployment using ansible scripts. In this case is there any way I can have some kind of placeholder in the Web App and Middleware and configure the URLs while running the docker image on the server? Or for the fact any URL that I might use in the application (say - a DB URL etc)

Comment: you tagged `docker` - do you plan to release as docker containers? Then look into `docker network ...`. You can create a local network and use it to connect the two containers, independently of an IP or DNS entry that might change.

Comment: Most cloud environments include the ability to assign dns names to your virtual machines that you can use in lieu of the ip address. It doesn't really matter whether or not you're using Ansible or some other automation tool. We can probably give you a better answer if you (a) tell us *which* cloud environment you're using and (b) how you have tried to solve this problem so far.

Comment: it is a cloud environment for academic research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

We already use this method so it will work for sure.
you can save url in `environment.ts` and call it on the page required

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl : 'http://a.b.c.d:3000'
};
```

Service page to include url to service

```
  export class CServices {
      private url = environment.apiUrl;
constructor(){}

  checkfunction() {
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/api/', JSON.stringify(payload));
  }
    }
```

Comment: This will work if we know the IP is constant and know before hand. But what if, we have to bring down the VM and on recreating it a different IP gets assigned. We have to again update the app's code to reflect the IP change.

Comment: ok. Sorry i didn't get your issue at that time i will post if i find something